# twilio <gather> missing attributes c#

Tags: twilio

I'm writing an IVR application using Twilio in C#, and I'm trying to use the gather verb along with it's attributes: input, action, hints, and timeout.

If I write:

```
var gather = new Gather(input: "speech", action: Url.Action("PostSpeech"), timeout: 3);
```

Then the "hints" attribute is not available.  If I try to write it in like:

```
var gather = new Gather(input: "speech", action: Url.Action("PostSpeech"), timeout: 3, hints: "stuff, things");
```

Then it tells me that 'The best overload for Gather does not have a parameter named hints'

Alternatively, if I try:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
response.Gather(action: Url.Action("PostSpeech"), timeout: 3, hints: "stuff, things");
```

Then the "input" attribute is not made available to me, similar to the above.
My understanding is that all of the attributes listed here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather

should be made available no matter how I use the gather verb.  There are a few other attributes (like profanityFilter) that also do not work in either case, but that's irrelevant to me at the moment.

How can I get the four aforementioned attributes to work here? Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a bug?

P.S. I'm using the Twilio nuget package v5.5.2 as well as the Twilio.AspNet.Mvc package v5.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Phil mentioned above, there was already an open issue for this on Github, and I thought I'd tackle it today.

I went ahead and also added all the other missing properties for completion. You can see my PR [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/pull/385). It should get merged any time now and hopefully packaged pretty soon.

In the future this won;t be an issue and the library should pretty much follow the API changes instantaneously, but that's unfortunately not the case right now.

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the library hasn't caught up with the product yet. I found [this open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/379) and I am now chasing up internally to get this done.

In the meantime, as far as I'm aware (and I'm not a C# developer at all), the best way to generate the TwiML you need is with a more liberal XML generator or by hand. Hopefully I can get an update to the library out for you quickly though.

Sorry for not a great answer.

Comment: Understood.  On a related note, is there a specific reason we're limited to supplying 50 hints in a single gather?  I'd like for the speech recognizer to be able to recognize (and return the correct spelling of) over 100 names, but I'm not sure how to go about that while still using Twilio's speech recognition.  It may be that the cap of 50 hints is temporary while it's still in beta, or it may be that google doesn't allow more hints, and therefore it's out of Twilio's hands.

Comment: Top question, I'll go ask the team.